# OnevsrestClassifier and random forest

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to reproduce the example [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html) but using `RandomForestClassifer`.

I can't see how to transform this part of the code

```
# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(svm.SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True,
                                 random_state=random_state))
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

I tried

```
# Learn to predict each class against the other
classifier = OneVsRestClassifier(RandomForestClassifier())
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).decision_function(X_test)
```

but I get

> AttributeError: Base estimator doesn't have a decision_function
>   attribute.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well you should know what is `decision_function` used for. Its only used with a SVM classifier reason being it gives out the distance of your data points from the hyperplane that separates the data, whereas when you do it using a `RandomForestClassifier` it makes no sense. You can use other methods that are supported by RFC. You can use `predict_proba` if you want to get the probabilities of your classified data points.

Here is the reference for the supported [functions](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)

Just to mention RFC do supports `oob_decision_function`, which is the out of bag estimate on your training set.

So just replace your line like -

```
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict_proba(X_test)
```

or

```
y_score = classifier.fit(X_train, y_train).predict(X_test)
```